# Stripe Payment Details JSON Encoding Error

Tags: json, swift, stripe-payments

I have a payment data defined as this:

```
let paymentMethodParamsWrapper = PaymentMethodParamsWrapper(paymentMethodParams: paymentMethodParams)
let paymentMethodParamsData = try JSONEncoder().encode(paymentMethodParamsWrapper)
let paymentMethodParamsJson = String(data: paymentMethodParamsData, encoding: .init(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
```

and it's passed through the API request, but the error that I am getting is

> `Instance method 'encode(_:forKey:)' requires that 'STPPaymentMethodParams' conform to 'Encodable'`

On the part:

```
//MARK: PAYMENT INTENTS
struct PaymentMethodParamsWrapper: Encodable {
    let paymentMethodParams: STPPaymentMethodParams

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case paymentMethod
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(paymentMethodParams, forKey: .paymentMethod)
    }
}
```

STPPaymentParams:

```
public class STPPaymentMethodParams: NSObject, STPFormEncodable {
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for `STPPaymentMethodParams`. Is it declared `Encodable`

Comment: `STPPaymentMethodParams` is actually 1. Made by stripe, 2. Really really long. Here is its "identifier": `public class STPPaymentMethodParams: NSObject, STPFormEncodable {` I have updated the code to attempt to include the params.

Comment: I'm not familiar with stripe, but it looks like this `STPPaymentMethodParams` class is not
 compatible (does not conform to) Swift Encodable, 
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable  You may have to restructure your code and use the stripe classes directly, instead of wrapping this one into a `PaymentMethodParamsWrapper` struct.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help! I will try to look into this further :)